# Magento : Add customer login form

Tags: header, footer

How to add customer login form in header and footer in magento 1.9?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Magento StackExchange.Please describe your question.with what you try and where you stuck.no one give you full code to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Customer Login form anywhere in website just put below code and design it.No need to define in XML file..!

```
    <?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/loginPost'); ?>" method="post" >
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                <div class="fieldwrap">
                    <div class="filedblock">
                        <input type="text"  name="login[username]" class="required-entry validate-email" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Username') ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-form">
                    <div class="filedblock">
                        <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="required-entry validate-password" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="toplogin" title="<?php echo $this->__('Go') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><?php echo $this->__('Go') ?></button>
                    <div class="mini-login">
                        <a class="forgot-link" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getForgotPasswordUrl(); ?>">Forgot Password</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it's working for me.